# Update entry with XML post

Tags: safecracker, cartthrob, xml

First, thanks in advance for any input or direction.

Does anyone have an idea how I might be able to receive entry updates by XML? Specifically, I'm looking to integrate ShipStation with CartThrob, particularly receiving shipping updates. More about the process can be found here, in the "Receiving Shipping Notifications" section:

http://app.shipstation.com/content/integration/ShipStationCustomStoreDevGuide.pdf

I've been digging into accomplishing this with EE's Channel Forms (aka Safecracker), but not sure if I'm on the right path. I also reached out to the developers of Data Grab, but it's not quite the right fit.

If anyone could point me in the direction of a possible solution, I'd greatly appreciate getting moving down the right path.

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Chris, did you ever figure out an integration with Cartthrob and ShipStation's API? I'm in need of the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

DataGrab is the gold standard and was built for this. You can import XML at regularly scheduled intervals using Cron or via HTTP. Otherwise you'll have to build a custom add-on.

Comment: I second the recommendation for DataGrab as well. It's a brilliant add-on and will probably do just what you need when set up in conjunction with a cron.

Comment: I've gone both the route of DataGrab and building custom. Use DataGrab if you can. You may have to modify the way you want to work a bit, but it takes care of so much of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. I spoke with the developers at DataGrab, and they let me know that out of the box it won't accommodate what I'm looking for.

The issue is that I need to have a template that is listening for *incoming* posts from ShipStation. I still have some hunting to do.